# Could not load the “” image referenced from a nib in the bundle with identifier

Tags: swift, xcode, image

When I put my images in the playingwithcontainerviews folder, they show up on my app. When I put my images in my imagesofcuteanimals folder, they don't. I have targets selected for the folder. This is the error: Could not load the “” image referenced from a nib in the bundle with identifier.

[image: image of where the pictures of cute animals are located]

Comment: please use the `Assets.xcassets` it will be more organized and you don't need to care about the folder hierarchy

Answer (score 1):

The blue folder is reference type when you load the image access it like this

```
let img = UIImage(named:"folderName/imageName.jpeg")
```

**OR**

```
if let img = Bundle.main.path(forResource:"imageName",ofType:"jpeg",
 inDirectory:"folderName") { }
```